# SAS daylight savings time conversion SAS

Tags: sql, sas, dst

I am trying to do a time zone conversion in my program and am running into some difficulties. Below I have

```
data GMT_conv;
    set table;
    if city in ('Atlanta', 'Baltimore' , 'New York') then conv = -5;
    if city in ('Minneapolis') then conv = -6;
    if city in ('Salt Lake City') then conv = -7;
    if city in ('San Francisco') then conv = -8;
run;
```

however, this is only correct during not the summer months. Daylight savings time changes the 2nd Sunday in March and the First Sunday in Novemember. I cant think of a way to do this if statement (in either SAS or proc sql)

what I want:

```
if (between 2nd sunday in march and 1 sunday of november) 
       then conv +1;
```

any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use SAS's built in timezone functions and formats/informats, rather than rolling your own.

First, [SAS's help page on time zones](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/n0px72paaaqx06n1ozps024j78cl.htm) shows how to specify times with a time zone. Then, you can see how to use the [TZONES2U](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/p1q4fv9tnskuvwn1k6nfdglcfv6x.htm) function to convert SAS datetimes to UTC, or [TZONEU2S](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/nlsref/n1ien0skr1u9swn1f00w7hizdg9c.htm) to convert back.  That will automatically handle daylight savings time!

For example:

```
data time_data;
format dtval datetime17.;
input city $ dtval :datetime17.;
datalines;
Atlanta 08JUN2021:11:00:00
Baltimore 08JAN2021:11:00:00
Chicago 08JUN2021:11:00:00
Dallas 08JAN2021:11:00:00
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set time_data;
  length tz $32;
  if city in ('Atlanta','Baltimore') then tz='America/New_York';
  if city in ('Chicago','Dallas') then tz='America/Chicago';
  
  format dtval_utc datetime17.;
  dtval_utc = tzones2u(dtval,tz);
  time_diff = dtval-dtval_utc;
  
  format time_diff time8.;
run;
```

That shows the DST difference (note how Atlanta, in summer, is 4 hours off, but Baltimore, in winter, is 5 hours.)

You still need to be able to know what the right time zone is, of course; you can do that by hand, as you are doing initially and how I did in the example, or you can look it up to some extent (perhaps using the zip code and SASHELP.ZIPCODE).

Comment: So the reason I was trying to lay it out as I did was because of how my data is presented. First off I am only interested in the time of day here, not the date at all. My data is given as one column being the GMT date and another column being the GMT minute time (number of minutes past midnight GMT). I could do this method but I'm unsure how to join the minute time into the date and make it a SAS dateTime, and then I would have to truncate the time off at the end anyways. Doable but might be more difficult since im only working with about 8 cities anyways.

Comment: Time of day vs. datetime doesn't matter here - but for the daylight savings time component of course!  If everything's in UTC (that's the term you should use if you mean the timezoneless date/time), then put it into one field, use TZONEU2S, and then split it back the way you want.  Use `dhms()` to combine them  (`dt = dhms(date,0,0,time);`).  Don't write code to do this by hand, trust me - especially in 5 or 10 years then DST rules change and you don't remember you wrote this code!  SAS will fix their functions, you won't remember to.